# How to disable rotation for some views in ios7

Tags: view, ios7, orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to have some views/tableviews only be portrait(not rotatable) and some views can be rotated in one xcode project. How can I achieve this efffect?

Thanks a lot for your help!